# MS SQL server getting error 18456 sverity 14 state 8

Tags: sql-server, authentication

On my laptop, I'm running MS SQL 14, 17, and 19 Express (for testing).
I have software using a database.

In the software, I log into the database with `sa`.
It works using no password. When I use a password I get:

```
login failed for user sa Reason password did not match that for the login provided. 
Error 18456 severity 14 state 8.
```

The password I use is correct. I get the same error with all MS SQL versions.

SQL and Windows authentication are both enabled.
Also restarted the server several times.

I can't figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: I'm confused. If it's letting you log in with `sa` and no password, then `sa` doesn't have a password set, and any password you're supplying is, logically, not a password for `sa`.

Comment: Hi,If i set it to "no password" it works for 'sa'. However when i set a password for sa it doesnt work. I get a message in the program that 
[microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver] [SQL Server] Login failed for user 'sa'.
open connection.